PostgreSQL Query Incorrect Sorting Order for Alphanumeric Strings
I am trying to sort a column title from the table door with the following PostgreSQL query:
SELECT title
FROM door
ORDER BY
  CASE 
    WHEN title ~ '^\d+' THEN CAST(regexp_replace(title, '[^0-9]', '', 'g') AS INTEGER)
    ELSE NULL
  END ASC,
  CASE 
    WHEN title ~ '^\d+' THEN regexp_replace(title, '\d+', '', 'g')
    ELSE title
  END ASC;

The query currently produces the following result:
"DR-1"
"DR-01"
"DR-02"
"DR-03"
"DR-04"
"DR-100"
"DR-1001"
"DR-101"
"DR-102"
"DR-104"
"Entrance-1"
"Entrance-2"
"MY-Prefix-10-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-11-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-19-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-1-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-20-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-2-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-3-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-8-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-9-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-9-Entrance-2"
"MY-Prefix-9-Entrance-3"

However, I was expecting the result to be:
"DR-1"
"DR-01"
"DR-02"
"DR-03"
"DR-04"
"DR-100"
"DR-101"
"DR-102"
"DR-104"
"DR-1001"
"Entrance-1"
"Entrance-2"
"MY-Prefix-1-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-2-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-3-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-8-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-9-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-9-Entrance-2"
"MY-Prefix-9-Entrance-3"
"MY-Prefix-10-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-11-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-19-Entrance-1"
"MY-Prefix-20-Entrance-1"

The query is not correctly ordering the rows where the title column contains mixed prefixes and numeric segments, particularly the entries with the MY-Prefix pattern. I suspect this is due to the logic in the ORDER BY clause not properly handling the sorting of multi-segment alphanumeric strings.
I want to:
Sort rows where the numeric segment is extracted from title and ordered numerically.
Handle alphanumeric prefixes correctly so that entries like MY-Prefix-1-Entrance-1 appear before MY-Prefix-10-Entrance-1.

The sorting is correct. The string MY-Prefix-10 comes before MY-Prefix-2. If you want numeric sorting you should find a way to split this column into multiple ones that use the correct type. You'd only pay the cost of splitting once.  Using a regex is trying to do that, without  the benefit of indexing. You'd also pay the cost on every query

"MY-Prefix-20-Entrance-1" this should come at last but its coming in between

Yes, because you're ordering by a string so lexicographical ordering is used. Split the denormalized column or extract the numeric parts instead of using replacements

You need to extract the numeric part, not replace it. Use cast(regexp_substr(title,'\d+') as integer) to extract the first numeric match and cast it to an integer. That's just a temporary solution though. You'll have similar if the string format changes or if entrance numbers go above 9

That's one of the purposes of custom ICU collations. You can define a sorting method that treats numbers numerically, the way you wanted:  demo at db<>fiddle
CREATE COLLATION numerical( provider=icu
                           ,deterministic=false
                           ,locale='und-u-kn' );

Then you just tell your order by to use it:
SELECT title
FROM door
ORDER BY title COLLATE numerical;

The demo shows it's also faster than trying to handle that using regex and conditionals.

The following query uses REXEXP_REPLACE to extract the segments from title:
WITH
  door (title) AS (
    VALUES
      ('DR-1'),
      ('DR-01'),
      ('DR-02'),
      ('DR-03'),
      ('DR-04'),
      ('DR-100'),
      ('DR-1001'),
      ('DR-101'),
      ('DR-102'),
      ('DR-104'),
      ('Entrance-1'),
      ('Entrance-2'),
      ('MY-Prefix-10-Entrance-1'),
      ('MY-Prefix-11-Entrance-1'),
      ('MY-Prefix-19-Entrance-1'),
      ('MY-Prefix-1-Entrance-1'),
      ('MY-Prefix-20-Entrance-1'),
      ('MY-Prefix-2-Entrance-1'),
      ('MY-Prefix-3-Entrance-1'),
      ('MY-Prefix-8-Entrance-1'),
      ('MY-Prefix-9-Entrance-1'),
      ('MY-Prefix-9-Entrance-2'),
      ('MY-Prefix-9-Entrance-3')
  )
SELECT
  title
FROM
  door
ORDER BY
  REGEXP_REPLACE(title, '^(\D*).*', '\1') NULLS FIRST,
  NULLIF(REGEXP_REPLACE(title, '^\D*(\d*).*', '\1'), '')::INTEGER NULLS FIRST,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(title, '^\D*\d*(\D*).*', '\1') NULLS FIRST,
  NULLIF(REGEXP_REPLACE(title, '^\D*\d*\D*(\d*).*', '\1'), '')::INTEGER NULLS FIRST,
  title DESC;

NULLIF is used to address missing numeric segments that cause exceptions when attempting to cast an empty string to an integer. Ordering by title DESC at the end of the list ensures that titles with leading zeros in numerically equivalent segments will sort based on the number of leading zeros.
